# Why doesn't 'perl -i' change a file in-place?

Tags: perl

My setup: perl 5.20.2

The file is changed in-place, as expected, with this code:

```
echo abc > test.txt
perl -i -ne 's/b/x/;print' test.txt
```

But here, the output is printed to `stdout` and the file is emptied. Why?

```
echo abc > test.txt
perl -i -ne 's/b/x/;push@a,$_;END{print for @a}' test.txt
```

Comment: Which file do you expect the END to add to? You only reach it after you've iterated through all the files passed add parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`END` blocks aren't part of the `-i -n` magic.

`-n` wraps an implicit `while (<>)` around (most of) your code, and `-i` causes files handled by `<>` to be overwritten.

However, as noted [in the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-n*), `BEGIN` and `END` blocks live *outside* that implicit loop, and aren't affected by `-i`.  There's nothing causing your `print` to go anywhere by `stdout`.

Comment: This is really more about the `-i` docs than the `-n` docs, though.

Comment: @Igor:  If you want to the functional equivalent to what you intended with the END block, then use [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) instead.

Comment: @cjm The `-i` docs don't mention `BEGIN` and `END` at all, which is the key difference between the two examples.

Comment: Yeah, it's more implicit in knowing that the `<>` construct can involve multiple files, so you have to print before it changes to the next file.  (The end of the last file is a special case of changing files.)

Comment: With the tip of @Miller, the solution is `perl -i -ne 's/b/x/;push@a,$_;next unless eof;print for @a' test.txt`